# Twitter Bootstrap code copied and not loading

Tags: css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have copied the following [template](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html) over to my CI [install](http://jzm.co.nz/clients/farm/index.php/admin) to use the css.  I am unsure why that css is not loading but it is a direct copy from the example.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css have 567 lines and the original one have .. 3365!

You : http://jsfiddle.net/ayottepl/EnSwQ/

The original : http://jsfiddle.net/ayottepl/7dCTw/

Just change the css in you're and it works!

Comment: Thanks,  I had copied and pasted that .css but I had to do a file save for it to work.